# Mailed in One-time Payment by Check

Tags: credit-card, repayment

I make payments to my monthly credit card account via pay by phone. Two months ago my boyfriend made a one time payment on my credit card account (payment was mailed via check). I resumed by pay by phone, and the credit card company added his checking account info on my account. They withdrew the next payment from his account and not from my banking account.

When I called the credit card co they told me that they cannot remove his bank account information because of federal law or requirement. I spoke with a supervisor and was told his banking account number will be deleted from my credit card account. As of 10/28/13, his banking account number is still listed on my credit card account.

Is this legal? When I signed up for pay by phone I had to give authorization and give them my routing number, etc. My boyfriend's payment was a one-time transaction. What can I do to get his banking account number on my credit card account?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Why did they add it to begin with? If your boyfriend didn't authorize it - they are not allowed to do that.

Comment: As littleadv says, this makes no sense. But, how about _you_ mail them a paper check next time instead of paying by phone, and then _your_ checking account number will replace your boyfriend's checking account number in what seems a weird system, and then you are all set to continue making payments by phone, and your checking account is the one from which the withdrawals will occur in the future.

Comment: Where? Would you tag your question with your location?

Answer (score 3):

I do know that a blank check has all the information they need for the electronic transfer. They probably add it as a customer service to streamline future payments. Though I don't think automatically adding it makes good business sense. It is possible that the form used to submit the check included a line to added the account to the list of authorized accounts.  He might have been lucky he didn't set up a recurring payment.

I would check the website to see if there is a tool to remove the account info from the list of payment options. There has to be a way to edit the list so that if you change banks you can update the information, yet not keep the old accounts on the list.

Talk to customer service if the website doesn't have a way of removing the account. Tell them that you have to edit the account information. And give them your info. If they balk at the change tell them that they could be committing fraud if the money is pulled from an unauthorized account.

Comment: Doesn't any vendor need a specific agreement to authorize a direct debit with no new check? Can't OP claim a fraudulent deduction from boyfriend's account if there was no authorization?

Comment: I don't think automatically adding it makes good business sense. It is possible that the form used to submit the check included a line to added the account to the list of authorized accounts.  He might have been lucky he didn't set up a recurring payment.

Comment: I have one direct debit, for a mortgage, and it required a VOIDed check, along with a long authorization form. This process sounds lacking in security.